# removing some dom elements after hard reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to remove some DOM elements if they're below a `#point` position.

Sometimes works, sometimes - doesn't.

After hard reloading the page (`Ctrl F5`) - it never works. Elements are not removed.

After just `F5` - mainly works.

Any help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var aoff = $('#point').position();
    var apoint = aoff.top;
    $('.bpart').each(function(){
        let boff = $(this).position();
        let bpoint = boff.top + $(this).height();
        if(bpoint > apoint){$(this).remove();}
    });
});
```

Comment: Does your page have images? After a hard reload the browser has to download the images again, and during that time the image elements have a height of 0px.

Comment: @yts - yes, each `bpart` has an image, but I hope `document.ready` ensures to wait till images are inside the DOM.

Comment: @qadenza document.ready does not wait for page load. Read about it here https://api.jquery.com/ready/
You can either change to wait for page load, or use a library like imagesLoaded  (https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) before calculating the heights.

Comment: @yts - how to wait for the page is completely loaded, including images, without a library?

Comment: @qadenza using `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready` should do the trick

Comment: @yts - it works, thanks, you should place your comment as answer.

Comment: @qadenza Glad I could help. Added it as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info you gave about F5 vs hard refreshes really helped narrow down the problem!

The problem is that your code is running before the image are loaded. Because of that, the image elements have a height of 0px, which causes your JS to not function properly.

To fix this, instead of waiting for `$(document).ready` before running your code, wait for `$(window).load`. This will fire after the images on the page are already loaded.